# How to set y-axis to Thousands in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale, yaxis

I have the following code to create a set of 2 x 2 plots in Pytho using Jupyter. Problem is that the left-y-label of the fourth plot (right-down) collides with the right-y-label of the third. I tried to change the scale of the left-y-label of the fourth plot to thousands, so instead of showing -1000, 0, 1000 etc. it would just shoe 1, 0, 1 giving then enough room for the title. How can I do that?

Following my code:

```
    #Testing 2 x 2 plots for FO reporting

plt.figure(figsize=(15,9))

#First Plot

ax1=plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.title("Downhole Pressure")
ax1.plot(Time, Downhole_pressure, 'b', markersize=2, label="Downhole pressure")
plt.xlabel("Injection time", fontsize=10)
plt.xlim(0,80)
plt.ylabel("Pressure, (psi)", fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(6500,7500)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.999,.89), prop={'size': 10})

ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(Time, Slurry_rate,'m', markersize=2, label="Slurry")
ax2.plot(Time, Proppant_rate, 'g', markersize=2, label="Proppant")
plt.ylabel("Injection rate, (BPM))", fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(0,100)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.879,.825), prop={'size': 10})

#Second Plot

ax1=plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.title("Fracture Width")
ax1.plot(Time, Max_Frac_Witdth, 'b', markersize=2, label="Max")
ax1.plot(Time, Mean_Frac_Width, 'r', markersize=2, label="Mean")
plt.xlabel("Injection time", fontsize=10)
plt.xlim(0,80)
plt.ylabel("Fracture width, (mm)", fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.84,.89), prop={'size': 10})

ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(Time, Slurry_rate,'m', markersize=2, label="Slurry")
ax2.plot(Time, Proppant_rate, 'g', markersize=2, label="Proppant")
plt.ylabel("Injection rate, (BPM))", fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.879,.775), prop={'size': 10})

#Third Plot

ax1=plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.title("Fracture Height")
ax1.plot(Time, Max_Frac_Ver_Pos, 'b', markersize=2, label="Max")
ax1.plot(Time, Min_Frac_Ver_Pos, 'r', markersize=2, label="Min")
ax1.plot(Time, Frac_Ver_Height, 'darkblue', markersize=2, label="Fracture Vertical Height")
plt.xlabel("Injection time", fontsize=10)
plt.xlim(0,80)
plt.ylabel("Fracture Vertical Position (ft)", fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-200,400)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.99,.6), prop={'size': 10})

ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(Time, Slurry_rate,'m', markersize=2, label="Slurry")
ax2.plot(Time, Proppant_rate, 'g', markersize=2, label="Proppant")
plt.ylabel("Injection rate, (BPM))", fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.82,.775), prop={'size': 10})

#Fourth Plot

ax1=plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.title("Fracture Length")
ax1.plot(Time, Max_Frac_Trans_Pos, 'b', markersize=2, label="Max")
ax1.plot(Time, Min_Frac_Trans_Pos, 'r', markersize=2, label="Min")
ax1.plot(Time, Frac_Trans_Length, 'darkblue', markersize=2, label="Fracture Transversal Length")
plt.xlabel("Injection time", fontsize=10)
plt.xlim(0,80)
plt.ylabel("Fracture Transversal Position (ft)", fontsize=10)

plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(-2e3,3e3)) #tried, didn't work
#plt.ylim(-2e3,3e3) #tried, didn't work

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.99,.6), prop={'size': 10})

ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(Time, Slurry_rate,'m', markersize=2, label="Slurry")
ax2.plot(Time, Proppant_rate, 'g', markersize=2, label="Proppant")
plt.ylabel("Injection rate, (BPM))", fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.82,.775), prop={'size': 10})

plt.savefig('side-by-side_09.png', dpi=300)
#plt.show()
plt.gcf().clear()
plt.close('all')
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let enough place for the titles, you could add the line

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

before saving the figure. It will optimize the position of the axis.

To change the offset of the axis, so that the yticks are showing 1, -1, use

```
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=1000)
```